# Mediaplayer freezes while preparing url audio

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

Am using `mediaplayer` to play URL songs in android APP, while `mediaplayer.prepare()` method called app was freezing I'm using `async Task` for handling. But it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`.
no need for AsyncTask

> Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the
>   datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare()
>   or prepareAsync(). For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which
>   returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been
>   buffered.